# Node.js exec call never calls callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a Node.js script which makes a call to `exec` but it never calls the callback. The code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("{COMMAND} > results.log", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('callback called!'); // this never gets called.
});
```

I'm using `async` lib and I'm relying on the `exec` callback to be called so I can in turn call an `async` callback to continue execution flow. The command does indeed get executed, as I see the output to the `results.log` file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your process does not write to stdout.

Comment: In my case I was running node with watch and watch was restarting my server when it was the file get written in my command.

Answer (score 2):

You're piping the returned result into another file, so it never returns to Node.

```
exec("{COMMAND}", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('callback called!'); // this never gets called.
});
```